# How can I Calculate a homes average amperage based on kwh?

Tags: power-consumption

I'm trying to gauge to what (approx)capacity my panel is being utilized. Is using the number of hours in a month and the power meters kwh during said month, than converting that to amps a semi accurate way to measure?

Comment: As the reply by Simon B points out, *average* utilisation is totally irrelevant - panel capacity should be based on peak utilisation. There may be a calculation for panel size required by your local electrical code, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can work out the average amperage fairly easily.  Divide your monthly kWh figure by the number of hours in a month, and you get the average kW load.  Multiply by 1000 to convert to watts.

Divide the wattage by your local mains voltage and you get the average amps.

How much use the result will be to you is another matter.  Real loads are highly variable and just knowing the average doesn't tell you anything about how close you are to hitting the capacity of your installation at peak loads.

Comment: +1 Also, just for some colour, the average UK household current would be 2.2A